# DNS server hostname.domain.com

Tags: dns, bind

I have a BIND server setup on my Ubuntu box and it works great if I navigate to `server.home.com` I was wondering if there is a way to set it up so that I can just type `home.com` Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your zone file on your server you probably have something like:

```
$ORIGIN home.com.

server      A     192.168.10.1
```

You can add another record like this:

```
@           A     192.168.10.1
```

This will make home.com resolve to 192.168.10.1.